# Which is the right way to pass "t" to child components with react-i18next?

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

My App looks like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import { I18n } from 'react-i18next';
import Home from '../Home/Home'
import Products from '../Products/Products'
import Navbar from '../Navbar/Navbar'
import NotFound from '../NotFound/NotFound'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <I18n ns="translations">
      {
        (t, { i18n }) => (
          <Router>
            <div>
              <Navbar />
              <div>{t('home.meta')}</div>
              <Switch>
                <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
                <Route path='/products' component={Products} />
                <Route component={NotFound} />
              </Switch>
            </div>
          </Router>
        )
      }
      </I18n>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Which is the correct way to have translated strings also in child components?
If I want to render "Page not found" or "Pagina non trovata" based on used language, my NotFound component is

```
import React from 'react'
import { Message, Icon } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import styles from './styles.css'

const NotFound = () => (
  <Message negative size='massive' className={styles.errormsg}>
    <Message.Header>
      <h1>404</h1>
      <p>Page Not Found</p>
    </Message.Header>
    <Icon name='frown' size='massive' className={styles.iconCenter} />
  </Message>
)

export default NotFound
```

What do I have to do in order to be able to use

```
<p>{t('pagenotfound')}</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

i suggest start using the render prop or hoc not on your app component but on components on level page. from there depending on component nested pass down t via props or again use the render prop or hoc.